# Filtering a dataframe using Lambda in Python

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have two data frames in python: df and list:

```
data1 = [[0, ("a","b")], [1, ("d","e")], [2, ("a","e")],[3,("f", "g")],[4,("c","h")]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['Row', 'Letters'])
data2 = [[0,"a"],[1,"b"],[2,"c"]]
list = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['Row', 'Letters'])
```

I now want to filter down df for only rows such that *any* item in df['Letters'] is found in list['Letters']

The Any function works fine for individual rows:

```
any(item in df["Letters"][1] for item in list['Letters'])
any(item in df["Letters"][2] for item in list['Letters'])
```

correctly returns False and True, respectively.

Now how do I filter down the entire dataframe?

I tried the following code:

```
new_df = df[df.apply(lambda x : any(item in x["Letters"] for item in list), axis=1)]
```

which returns an empty dataframe when I want to return only rows 0, 2 and 4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do not use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dataframe constructor with `stack` then compare using `series.isin` with `any` for `level=0`

```
df[pd.DataFrame(df['Letters'].tolist()).stack().isin(list_['Letters']).any(level=0)]
```

---

```
  Row Letters
0    0  (a, b)
2    2  (a, e)
4    4  (c, h)
```

Note: I have change the `list` variable where you save the list as `list_` since you should not have a variable name same as a builtin function

benchmarking for a larger dataframe:

```
m = pd.concat([df]*10000,ignore_index=True)
%%timeit
m[pd.DataFrame(m['Letters'].tolist()).stack().isin(list_['Letters']).any(level=0)]
#25.3 ms ± 1.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
m.loc[~m['Letters'].apply(lambda x: set(x).isdisjoint(set(list_['Letters'])))]
#644 ms ± 8.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
m[m.Letters.apply(lambda x : any(item in list_.Letters.to_numpy().tolist() for item in x))]
#665 ms ± 13.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
m.loc[m['Letters'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x).intersection(set(list_['Letters']))) > 0)]
#707 ms ± 56.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Brilliant!  This also works well.  Another interesting approach.  I appreciate the time spent looking through the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using set intersection, we convert each tuple into set and check if `len` of `set intersection` is `> 1`:

```
df.loc[df['Letters'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x).intersection(set(lst['Letters']))) > 0)]

   Row Letters
0    0  (a, b)
2    2  (a, e)
4    4  (c, h)
```

You can also use [`isdisjoint method`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/isdisjoint.html) to get the result

```
df.loc[~df['Letters'].apply(lambda x: set(x).isdisjoint(set(lst['Letters'])))]
```

Comment: This works, thanks very much.  Would not have thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
data1 = [[0, ("a","b")], [1, ("d","e")], [2, ("a","e")],[3,("f", "g")],[4,("c","h")]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['Row', 'Letters'])
data2 = [[0,"a"],[1,"b"],[2,"c"]]
list1 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['Row', 'Letters'])

new_df = df[df.Letters.apply(lambda x : any(item in list1.Letters.to_numpy().tolist() for item in x))]
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
   Row Letters
0    0  (a, b)
2    2  (a, e)
4    4  (c, h)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.  I tried this and I got the error:  AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'.  Perhaps I'm behind on updates?

Comment: @SM_Erd may be yes, try `.values` instead of `to_numpy()` then

Comment: That did it.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks again.